# How can I get AWS cloudwatch logs into GCP stack driver logs viewer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda, google-stackdriver

I have set up the "connector account" thing in Stackdriver, and I'm able to see metrics in GCP, which is super cool! I would now like to also get all cloudwatch logs into google's logging tool. Can this be done with the connector account as well? Or will I have to write a lambda to ship those off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2023, Google's officially documented answer is [use BindPlane (Open Telemetry) agents in your infra](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/bindplane/on-premise-hybrid-logging) to collect your logging and metrics and ship them to GCP, and they claim at no cost for the service but do not indicate how that arrangement works.

The AWS Connector referenced by the OP are now deprecated: [Deprecation: AWS Cloudwatch Metric Ingestion](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/deprecations/aws-cloudwatch-metrics-ingestion). As a replacement for the deprecated service, Google documentation recommends [running Prometheus Exporter in an EC2 instance](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/aws-prometheus-cloudwatch) to ship metrics to GCP, but it doesn't ship logs.

Additional resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/architecture/hybrid-and-multi-cloud-monitoring-and-logging-patterns?hl=en
- https://cloud.google.com/architecture/logging-on-premises-resources-with-bindplane?hl=en
- https://cloud.google.com/architecture/monitoring-on-premises-resources-with-bindplane?hl=en
- https://observiq.com/blog/observiq-expands-partnership-with-google-cloud-to-support-opentelemetry/

Comment: It's really infuriating how buried logs are in AWS. Very poor logging services.

Comment: Agreed, @askdesigners. There's a reason that so many log aggregators and shipping solutions have sprung up in the wake of AWS.

Comment: Why the down vote, down-voter? Is this not accurate information relevant to the OP?

Comment: AWS fanbois are not a rational bunch...

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate AWS CloudWatch to send metrics to the Google StackDriver. For more information please read these documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-aws)[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_aws).

Regarding your Lamba question I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785818/how-to-send-lambda-logs-to-stackdriver-instead-of-cloudwatch) link that might be helpful. I would also recommend reviewing the following [best practice](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/#create-account-bp) when using a Stackdriver account to monitor any number of GCP projects and AWS accounts.

Comment: Yes I did read those docs, and have hat working. Metrics are there. However I'd also like to have _logs_ in GCP. That other stackoverflow post is the first one I found, and it too only addresses metrics.

My question is specifically about logs, and if the "connector account" thing in GCP should also collect logs, or if I need to build my own solution for that. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: You can only use connector account for stackdriver monitoring and it doesnt work in the stackdriver logging.

Comment: ah ok, that's disappointing. :p

Comment: If this feature is very important to you, I would like to suggest you to raise a Feature Request in Google's Issue Tracker,  so that it might help you get the feature that you have requested. I recommend you to "star" it to increase visibility and stay updated about its implementation.
https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers